# 'is not a function' on calling an method within the same constructor function (JS)

Tags: javascript, methods, runtime-error, class-method

I wanted to call a method within a method of the same class.

```
function Dialog() {

this.close = function() {
    //code
};

this.dialog = document.createElement("div");
this.dialog.onclick = function() {
    this.close();
}
document.body.appendChild(this.dialog);
}

var test = new Dialog();
```

I searched for anwers but nothing helped: I still get `TypeError: this.close is not a function` in the console of my browser when I click the the div.

Comment: `this` inside `onclick` is the element that is clicked

Comment: FYI: You are not using classes here. You are using a "constructor function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `function() { ... }` it changes what `this` is while inside the function. You either need to bind the function to `this` or use an arrow function `() => { ... }`.

Using bind:

```
var handleClick = function() {
    this.close();
};

this.dialog.onclick = handleClick.bind(this)
```

Using arrow function:

```
this.dialog.onclick = () => {
    this.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using close(){} instead of doing this.close = function(){}. See example below.

```
function Dialog() {
    close(){
        //code
    };

    this.dialog = document.createElement("div");
    this.dialog.onclick = function() {
        this.close();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(this.dialog);
}

var test = new Dialog();
```